# load result of async await into variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to obtain the result of this 'response' into a variable that I can manipulate later. This is what I have so far

```
const url = my-url
const axios = require('axios').default;

async function getUser() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      //console.log(response); // this is what I need
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }


let results = await getUser();
console.log(results) // take results and do something with it
```

I do not understand why I cannot access the results.

Comment: @Phil I have edited my question, that may have been a typo

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything specifically wrong with your code. What happens? Do you have any errors reported?

Comment: @Phil, sorry I should have included that `await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: @Phil I wasn't sure if there was a better way overall, thanks.

Comment: To fix that, put the code `let results = await getUser();` and `console.log(results)` inside an `async` function and call that function. (alternatively, run your code in an environment that supports top-level await, though that solution may not be practical)

Comment: This appears to be the _"top level body of a module"_. If it's not then there's something missing from your question

Answer (score -1):

This is called a [top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) and not all runtimes support it

...I assumed you are not inside a function because i saw the require statement `const axios = require('axios').default;` on the top